# insert command into start cmd

Tags: batch-file, redirect, cmd, tfs-power-tools

I am trying to insert the content of a text file into a `cmd`
console, by using:

```
start cmd.exe < c:\text.txt
```

I also tried:

```
start cmd.exe | c:\text.txt
```

However, the both open the `cmd` shell but nothing gets passed.

My point being in the end that I have a scheduler jenkins, and I pass the content of the text file inside the console when opening it with the `start` command. So I am not simply trying to print to the `cmd` console; I could just use `echo` for that different case.

Comment: the answer below is not exactly responding to the question, but the conversation below has a nice hackish but elegant solution which responds to the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

from CMD.exe itself,

```
type C:\Text.txt
```

If it is a batch file, then

```
type C:\Text.txt
pause
```

or to just see the content, use more

```
more C:\Text.txt
```

If you want to actually run commands from the file instead of trying to insert the commands from the text file into the cmd console, you should rather build it as a batch file which is an executable. you do this by renaming the file to either `.bat` or `.cmd`

you then insert you commands into the file and execute it by either double clicking the file or running it from a scheduler etc. Here is an example of a batch or cmd file:

```
echo Please wait while I execute.
tp merge $/ServerFolderA $/ServerFolderB
```

So just a few explanations on your initial commands. When you ran:

```
start cmd.exe | c:\text.txt
```

you actually told the system to run multiple executables from a single command. The pipe commands is like separator to specify each command. so this:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 | nslookup www.google.com | cmd.exe | c:\text.txt
```

will actually do all of those commands in sequence, first it will ping, the do nslookup, open cmd.exe then open c:\text.txt

Here you were on the right track, but my guess is you had a single line in the file and not a new line.

```
start cmd.exe < Text.txt
```

That will use the Text.txt file as an answer file so if I edit it and insert the following:

```
echo This is an answer file
ping 127.0.0.1
ping 10.132.4.99
echo Completed all commands
```

and then run `start cmd.exe < Text.txt` it will execute everything in sequence. This difference here is it reads the file line by line and displays each commands it runs. so your output will be something like this:

```
C:\>echo this is an answer file
this is an answer file
ping 127.0.0.1

Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
ping 10.132.4.99

Pinging 10.132.4.99 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.132.4.99: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=254

Ping statistics for 10.132.4.99:
   Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
   Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 8ms, Average = 4ms
```

As you can see this works perfectly, but it displays each command you are running except, it does not run the very last command which is `echo Completed all commands`. So to run all commands you always have to add a new line after your last commands. When however you rename it to `.cmd` it will just run the commands without displaying the commands to run and runs each line until the end. The other issue with the answer file is it reads line by line, so having 3 new lines with no text in the answer file will result in something like this

```
C:\>
C:\>
C:\>
```

So having just this in the answer file:

```
ping 127.0.0.1
```

will not work as it is a single line without the enter section.

but by just adding a new line after it will make it work.

I hope all this makes some sense.

Comment: thank you but i am not certain.. it flashes the console and then it goes away, have no time to actually see if there is anything inside..

Comment: are you doing this within a batch file? if it is, then type pause at the end of the batch file.. I will amend the answer.

Comment: What's the content of your text file?

Comment: the content is "hello"

Comment: @GerhardBarnard iam doing this inside a console just to try it out; then ill put it in a scheduler

Comment: did you type exactly that? `type C:\Text.txt` remember type is a command. so you need to add it to the console. so you console should show `C:\>type C:\Text.txt`

Comment: yea i am , ok it does open it, but there is nothing in the console

Comment: if you type `more C:\Text.txt`

Comment: i mean it's on c:\Desktop but same thing no?

Comment: no it just opens it .i do   
 'start cmd.exe  type   C:\text.txt   pause'

Comment: no... just do what I said. `type C:\Text.txt` only, not Start cmd etc. just what I said.

Comment: ok thank you thatwas my mistake. it does print it inside that same very console. but my point is i have a jenkins scheduler and i need to open a cmd file and pass the content of a text file into it that console

Comment: ok, then the question is not the same. wht is the point of pushing display to console only? is it for log file monitoring? what do you intend to do with that data?

Comment: i mean it was my question. Well, so yea iam trying to have it run commands on a database. I am trying to open a console, with the content from a different text file being its commands; and those commands would be executed by the console when it opens. I just edited it to be more clear.

Comment: ok, that is completely different then. You want to execute commands with additional paramaters, sort of like "answer files"

Comment: ok. So I need to first know what the commands are you needing to run. does it stay constant? what are these commands exactly? lastly, are these commands issues in a specific type of console or can they be issued from cmd.exe

Comment: but at least, give me an example of what is in the text.txt file.

Comment: ok so iam actually useing the tfpt.exe console which is the developer command prompt console, which has for env variables and path the TFS variables.
And so, the content of the text file are similar to this:
tf merge  $/ServerFolderA   $/ServerFolderB

When i run them directly it does not work, neither does it work with cmd.exe actually, which explains my questioning.
iam doing 
'start pathof_tpft.exe < pathof_text.txt'  but not working too

Comment: why not just change the name of the .txt to .cmd and making sure tfpt.exe is in your path then do `tp merge $/ServerFolderA $/ServerFolderB` inside the file, then run `Text.cmd` as executable

Comment: ok let me wrap my head around that  and c how it would work out for a min. thanks! - brb

Comment: oh i see, smart, i did not know you could do that, that;s basically like using the console directly via a batch file? --..edit:  oh but i wanna use tfpt not cmd.exe

Comment: i get it now, that's very smart!! :=))

Comment: yes it works!, i have to fix my path, but it does make the calls. i have to put the path of the cmd file within the server and then call it from there. i think that way it will be able to use the tfpt.exe. Otherwise the scheduler would depend on my station being online. However, let me run a local check and get back to you soon. thanks!

Comment: ok, please mark the answer as correct once you feel that I assisted you :)

Comment: do you want to edit your answer so i can rate it?  also i am going to add print statements to see if anything happens

Comment: Yes, I will edit the answer once you confirm my help worked for you, then I will add everything that we discussed with explanation.